# How do I toggle to katakana input from hiragana with fcitx-mozc text entry? (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, input-method, japanese, fcitx, mozc

I am using a Japanese 109-key keyboard. I can use the zenkaku (全角) toggle key to switch between romaji and hiragana input, but the katakana/hiragana/romaji (カタカナ・ひらがな・ローマ字) toggle key has no effect.

(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do it this way:

- to type Roman letters or western symbols >> Mozc off
- to type Hiragana >> mozc on
- to type Katakana >> mozc on hiragana input, then press F7
- to type Hankaku-Katakana >> mozc on hiragana input Hiragana, then F8

Open mozc setup (i.e., Mozc settings) and assign your favorite keys

Katakana/Hiragana/Romaji keys are for some particular input methods available in Windows and are from the 20th century...

Comment: Where can I find the settings to modify these?

Comment: @CLOVIS, hope you find how https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053157/japanese-default-input-mode/1053767#1053767

Answer (score 0):

You can also type Katagana if you you right click on the mozc image on the task bar and select composition mode, there you will have the option of selecting which characters you want to use.