# Japanese default input mode

Tags: language-support, input-language, japanese, mozc

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC, I use `Mozc` to input Japanese. Its default input mode is direct input(input English), I need to change it to hirakana everytime after restarting PC. Can I make hirakana to default?

Comment: Alternative choice of your desktop, unity, xfce, mate. # sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop/unity-desktop/mate-desktop. And install fcitx-mozc then the problem and many other problem are solved. Now, it seems too many bugs and mis-concepts are in gnomeshell 18.04.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I don't think I will change the DE, another DE might solve this problem but they have theirs. I hope there is a solution in GNOME.

Comment: I tried my best to answer the original question, I hope it works. I am not sure this would work for the all of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS users.

Comment: This was added in a [recent version](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/docs/configurations.md#fixed-composition-mode-per-engine) of ibus-mozc. No compiling needed! You can edit config file `~/.config/mozc/ibus_config.textproto`, under `engines {}` in the curly brackets add a line `composition_mode: HIRAGANA`. Save and apply with `ibus write-cache; ibus restart`.

Answer (score 3):

Many Japanese users say that ibus-mozc has many bugs or uncomfortable features. So I think, until the bug-fix comes you can use other InputMethodEngine for a while.

```
sudo apt install fcitx-mozc
```

or

```
sudo apt install uim-mozc
```

After install open **System preference > Language**

[image: IME]

Please change this into your choice iBus/fcitx/uim and restart computer or your session.

---

If you are keen to stick on iBus and you can build Mozc from the source code with a handy Mozc support package Mozc UT. I omit how you download and extend source files.

```
$ vim src/mozc/src/unix/ibus/property_handler.cc

...
// Some users expect that Mozc is turned off by default on IBus 1.5.0 and later.
// https://code.google.com/p/mozc/issues/detail?id=201
// On IBus 1.4.x, IBus expects that an IME should always be turned on and
// IME on/off keys are handled by IBus itself rather than each IME.
#if IBUS_CHECK_VERSION(1, 5, 0)
const bool kActivatedOnLaunch = true; //false;
#else
const bool kActivatedOnLaunch = true;
#endif  // IBus>=1.5.0
...
```

Then build and install this. This information is provided from [A wise programmer's blog "karelie"](https://www.karelie.net/install-ibus-mozc/) and [Glasse-age](http://ranats.github.io/2016/04/13/ibus-mozc-fixed.html)

---

If this is too much work for you, there's an alternative. You can switch **Composition Mode** by the hotkey.

First activate the Mozc then,  click on Mozc Icon on the menu bar.
Mozc Tool > Configuration Tools.

[image: Menu]

Like this.

[image: Mozc Settings]

The Mozc Settings Window should appear and click on the **Customize** button.

[image: Keymap Window]

When you click on the Command column, you can select actions for a hotkey, choose *set input mode to Hiragana*. Then you can assign your favourite hotkey, this example is for the **Hiragana** key that most of US keyboard layout doesn't have it. You may need to restart your computer after this setting.

*Note: I think the window and the menu bar look different on 18.04 but it's essentially the same, in my opinion and I hope this helps or gives you a hint.*

Comment: I set a shortcut to `set input mode to Hiragana`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check (1) your new shortcut is NOT reserved for another global shortcut keys already (2) You need to switch Mozc first (3) You need to restart computer after the setting changes.

Comment: Also this related issues of bugs about shortcut doesn't set Hiragana input.  https://github.com/google/mozc/issues/395

Comment: Thanks, I did all of them, still not working. I think I need to compromise to this inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

This was added in a [recent version](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/docs/configurations.md#fixed-composition-mode-per-engine) of ibus-mozc. No compiling needed!

You can edit config file `~/.config/mozc/ibus_config.textproto`, under `engines {}` in the curly brackets add a line `composition_mode: HIRAGANA`. Save and apply with `ibus write-cache; ibus restart`.

Answer (score 1):

## solution 1: recompile mozc with hiragana

A discussion can be found in [Is there a way to set hiragana as default?](https://github.com/google/mozc/issues/381) and [Enhancement Request: making initial mode customizable for ibus-mozc](https://github.com/google/mozc/issues/201):

Basically, you will need:

> ...is to replace `const bool kActivatedOnLaunch = false;` with `const bool kActivatedOnLaunch = true;` in `src/unix/ibus/property_handler.cc` then rebuild the ibus-mozc binary.

To rebuild [ibus-mozc](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159854/1076973):

1. Install the requirements to rebuild mozc

```
sudo apt install build-essential devscripts -y
sudo apt build-dep ibus-mozc -y
apt source ibus-mozc
```

2. `cd ~`
3. edit `./mozc*/src/unix/ibus/property_handler.cc`, replacing:

   - before:
     `const bool kActivatedOnLaunch = false;`
   - after:
     `const bool kActivatedOnLaunch = true;`
4. edit `./mozc*/src/protocol/commands.proto`, replacing:

   - before:

     ```
     enum CompositionMode {
     DIRECT = 0;
     HIRAGANA = 1;
     ```
   - after:

     ```
     enum CompositionMode {
     DIRECT = 1;
     HIRAGANA = 0;
     ```
5. building

   ```
   cd mozc*
   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b
   ```
6. install the new mozc build: `sudo apt install ibus-mozc*.deb`
7. restart

## solution 2: use the mozc default shortcuts to switch between japanese modes

The mozc's keys/shortcuts can be found from [ibuz-mozc menu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1053767/1076973). You can read it from the [ibus-mozc source-code](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/data/keymap/ms-ime.tsv) too.

To access the ibus-mozc configurations:

1. Click on `Gnome Status menu` (Gnome's top-left bar) > `IBus icon menu` (i.e. keyboard/input language selector) > Select `Japanese Mozc` input method.
2. Again, click on `Gnome Status Menu` > `IBuz` > `tools` > `Properties` > `Mozc Settings window`.
3. From `Keymap style` section > click on `customize` button (first one).

[image: ibus-mozc configurations]

So, the keys that binding *the japanese mode switchers* (i.e. hiragana, katakana, half-with etc) in a japanese JIS keyboard are bellow in *table 1*:

```
...
Composition Eisu    ToggleAlphanumericMode
Conversion  Eisu    ToggleAlphanumericMode
DirectInput Eisu    IMEOn
Precomposition  Eisu    ToggleAlphanumericMode
...
Composition Hankaku/Zenkaku IMEOff
Conversion  Hankaku/Zenkaku IMEOff
DirectInput Hankaku/Zenkaku IMEOn
Precomposition  Hankaku/Zenkaku IMEOff
...
Composition Muhenkan    SwitchKanaType
Conversion  Muhenkan    SwitchKanaType
Precomposition  Muhenkan    InputModeSwitchKanaType
...
```

And consider these keys too, in *table 2*.
Mainly if you have a real *non*-japanese keybard.
Look  the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>F#</kbd> switcher keys.

```
...
DirectInput F13 IMEOn
...
Composition Ctrl i  ConvertToFullKatakana
Conversion  Ctrl i  ConvertToFullKatakana
...
Composition Ctrl o  ConvertToHalfWidth
Conversion  Ctrl o  ConvertToHalfWidth
Composition Ctrl p  ConvertToFullAlphanumeric
Conversion  Ctrl p  ConvertToFullAlphanumeric
...
Composition Ctrl t  ConvertToHalfAlphanumeric
Conversion  Ctrl t  ConvertToHalfAlphanumeric
Composition Ctrl u  ConvertToHiragana
Conversion  Ctrl u  ConvertToHiragana
...
Composition F10 ConvertToHalfAlphanumeric
Conversion  F10 ConvertToHalfAlphanumeric
DirectInput F13 IMEOn
Composition F2  ConvertWithoutHistory
Composition F6  ConvertToHiragana
Conversion  F6  ConvertToHiragana
Composition F7  ConvertToFullKatakana
Conversion  F7  ConvertToFullKatakana
Composition F8  ConvertToHalfWidth
Conversion  F8  ConvertToHalfWidth
Composition F9  ConvertToFullAlphanumeric
Conversion  F9  ConvertToFullAlphanumeric
...
Composition Henkan  Convert
Conversion  Henkan  ConvertNext
DirectInput Henkan  Reconvert
Precomposition  Henkan  Reconvert
...
Composition Hiragana    InputModeHiragana
Conversion  Hiragana    InputModeHiragana
DirectInput Hiragana    IMEOn
Precomposition  Hiragana    InputModeHiragana
...
Composition Katakana    InputModeFullKatakana
Conversion  Katakana    InputModeFullKatakana
DirectInput Katakana    IMEOn
Precomposition  Katakana    InputModeFullKatakana
...
Composition Shift Muhenkan  ConvertToFullAlphanumeric
Conversion  Shift Muhenkan  ConvertToFullAlphanumeric
Precomposition  Shift Muhenkan  ToggleAlphanumericMode
...
Composition Kanji   IMEOff
Composition OFF IMEOff
Composition ON  IMEOn
Conversion  Kanji   IMEOff
Conversion  OFF IMEOff
Conversion  ON  IMEOn
DirectInput Kanji   IMEOn
DirectInput ON  IMEOn
Precomposition  ASCII   InsertCharacter
Precomposition  Kanji   IMEOff
Precomposition  OFF IMEOff
Precomposition  ON  IMEOn
...
```

## solution 3: bind your own shortcut keys

From the *solution 2*, you can insert new entries on that table.
The idea is replicate the *table 1*, but changing the key/shortcut combinations.

For example, my suggestions:

```
...
Composition Ctrl j  IMEOff
Conversion  Ctrl j  IMEOff
DirectInput Ctrl j  IMEOn
Precomposition  Ctrl j  IMEOff
Composition Ctrl b  SwitchKanaType
Conversion  Ctrl b  SwitchKanaType
Composition Ctrl y  ToggleAlphanumericMode
Conversion  Ctrl y  ToggleAlphanumericMode
DirectInput Ctrl y  IMEOn
Precomposition  Ctrl y  ToggleAlphanumericMode
...
```

If you are interested, you can read [MOZC's romaji-hiragana conversion table](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/data/preedit/romanji-hiragana.tsv) too.

## Solution 4: click on Ibus icon from Gnome

Click on `Gnome Status Menu` > `IBus` > `Input Mode` > select your desired input mode.

[image: Japanese modes from ibus-mozc]

*Solution 1* resolves your question, and the others solutions are all the possible ways to switch (and to set hiragana).

Comment: Reviewed and updated, with detailed steps and screenshots. Thanks for your moderations @Nmath

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version out. Now, there is a configuration file, and editing this in conjunction with changing an option in the settings does the trick for me (version 2.28.4715.102)

First, you need to go to the settings and change the input mode to "kana". **This step is very important.**

Then you need to edit a configuration file. The configuration file you need to edit is located in the `~/.config/mozc/` directory and is called `ibus_config.textproto`.

Thus, you need to edit this file. Browse to your home directory and open the file using your favourite text editor, in my case gedit:

`gedit ~/.config/mozc/ibus_config.textproto`

If you have a Japanese keyboard, replace the previous content with the following:

```
# `ibus write-cache; ibus restart` might be necessary to apply changes.
engines {
  name : "mozc-jp"
  longname : "Mozc"
  layout : "jp"
  layout_variant : ""
  layout_option : ""
  rank : 80
}
active_on_launch: True
```

If you don't have a Japanese keyboard, you might have to replace `"jp"` by `"default"` or something else.

I found this method at: https://github.com/google/mozc/issues/201

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I used solution 1 in the past and it worked for me. But now I cannot see `const bool kActivatedOnLaunch = false;` in the code. Probably it has been changed. I wonder if there is an updated solution.

Comment: I've posted one below.