# Enabling/installing Japanese input

Tags: keyboard, language-support, ibus, japanese

How do I get Japanese input on 18.04? I have gone and installed Japanese as a language and experimenting, I can change the language setting to Japanese and restart. This shows all my menus in Japanese. But I want to be able to use a regular US keyboard to produce Japanese characters.

I have installed `ibus-anthy` and I can 'switch' languages via the top right menu or the super+space key combination.

[image]

But in `ja` mode, English characters are still produced. My experience with different OSes has been that in a Japanese input 'mode', US key combinations will produce the appropriate hiragana, etc.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053157/japanese-default-input-mode/1053767?noredirect=1#comment1723901_1053767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to *Region & Language* and add the Anthy or Mozc input method to the active input sources. Once done, you can switch to Anthy (or Mozc) and start typing Japanese characters.

Comment: Awesome. 日本語でどうもありがとうございました!!

Comment: In 18.10, there seems to be no "Region and Language" (using Cinnamon desktop). Do you know where this went by any chance?

Comment: @Kingsley: It probably didn't go anywhere. _Region & Language_ is a GNOME thing, and the OP of this question is on Ubuntu with a GNOME desktop.