# How do I install japanese anthy ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: language-support, input-language, japanese

Third install of Ubuntu on 3rd machine. Never had an issue getting Japanese language (kana) input, but suddenly I can't find the settings I'm used to!

Trying to get Anthy installed, but it's not showing up in the Region & Language options. When searching for Japanese input sources, my options are:

- Japanese
- Japanese (Dvorak)
- Japanese (Kana 86)
- Japanese (Kana)
- Japanese (Macintosh)
- Japanese (OADG 109A)
- Japanese (PC-98)

Installing Japanese and Japanese (Kana) has given me the option to select them in my input methods, but input remains English.

Where can I find the settings/files to input text in Japanese kana?

---

This question can be considered a precursor to the solutions provided in this related question:

[Enabling/installing Japanese input](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083575/enabling-installing-japanese-input)

Comment: 1. Install the `ibus-anthy` package, 2. Relogin

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053157/japanese-default-input-mode/1053767#1053767, during this setting, open configuration panel and set the input mode to Kana from Romaji. You can install ibus-anthy (Gunner's suggestion)or fcitx-anthy instead of fcitx-mozc, but I am not sure it works perfectly as fcitx-mozc does.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, would that be via `sudo apt-get install ibus-anthy`?
@SadaharuWakisaka, are you recommending an alternative package to anthy? Can you give me more details because I do not understand what you are suggesting to do?

Comment: @PinkieB: Yes. Then, when you have logged out and logged in again, you should see _Japanese (Anthy)_ among the input sources. The ones you listed above are XKB keyboard layouts, and indeed not sufficient for inputting Japanese.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka: My understanding is that the OP is on a standard Ubuntu machine, i.e. with the GNOME desktop, and in that case it's not likely that any Fcitx method works very well.

Comment: https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/04/29/ubuntu-1804-ibus-mozc-ja/ This is what people suggest, and for me, the native Japanese depends type smoothly with the wise converter. Anthy makes me slow down, while Mozc offers me a bunch of suggestions and TAB auto-complete like a bash assist is useful. Sometimes ibus doesn't offer me inline converting in some applications. https://www.karelie.net/install-ibus-mozc-1804/ This is a work-around to fix the bugs. I am fond of ibus than fcitx, but since 14.04 ibus v1.5 often broken and is not beautifully working as it used to be.

Comment: I tried installing Mozc and now my ubuntu does not load. I get a black screen of death. Thanks for the comments but I will have to wait until I can unfreeze my system to try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After install the japanese language on a Gnome/Ubuntu 18.04:

1. Install, at least one, IMF (`ibus` comes by default on Ubuntu):

   - `sudo apt install ibus`, and/or;
   - `sudo apt install fcitx`
2. Install, at least one, japanese IME for your IMF:

   - if using `ibus`:

     - `sudo apt install ibus-mozc`, and/or;
     - `sudo apt install ibus-anthy`, and/or;
     - `sudo apt install ibus-kkc`, and/or;
     - `sudo apt install ibus-skk`.
   - if using `fcitx`:

     - `sudo apt install fcitx-mozc`, and/or;
     - `sudo apt install fcitx-anthy`, and/or;
     - `sudo apt install fcitx-kkc`, and/or;
     - `sudo apt install fcitx-skk`.

With that, select the input method (IME) from your language selector on icon tray (IMF).

- the IMF (`ibus`) on `Gnome Status Menu` (is represented by a language icon selector).
- all (my) selectable IMEs (portuguese, spanish, english, japanese-mozc, japanese-anthy, japanese-kkc, japanese-skk) from this IMF (`ibus`).

[image: ibus menu and selectables IMEs]

Or you can use the Gnome shortcut to fast-switch between IMEs: hold <kbd>Super</kbd> and press <kbd>Space</kbd>.

[image: gnome menu shortcut to select IMEs]